Diagrammatic computations in the theory with spontaneous symmetry breaking
I am looking for an reasonably detailed and instructive exposition of some computations with Feynman diagrams of a theory with spontaneous symmetry breaking (but with no Higgs mechanism). I wonder how multiple vacua are taken into account in such computations. Indeed the definition of propagator does depend on the choice of vacuum.
A theory which might be sufficient for my purposes is a quantization of the Lagrangian density
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\left((\partial\phi_1)^2+(\partial\phi_2)^2\right)-\frac{\mu^2}{2}(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)-\frac{\lambda}{4}(\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2)^2,$$
where $\lambda>0,\mu^2<0$, and $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are Hermitian scalar fields.

Popov's book on functional integral method develops the diagrammatic perturbation theory for non-relativistic superfluid in some detail.  You can easily adopt the result for K-G theory, only difference being the kinetic term.
But that would be pointless.  The very same book then proceeds to tell you that the gapless Goldstone boson makes just about every loop diagram explodes like a nuke in the IR.  You can renormalize away UV problem, but if you have IR divergence you are quite screwed.
Popov's own proposal is that you use the perturbation theory only to integrate out the modes down to some IR scale in the momentum-shell RG sense.  The resultant IR effective sigma model is then handled in the amplitude-phase basis.  I think nowadays most people in the field simply use symmetry argument to write down the sigma model, and skip the first step altogether.
And no, perturbation theory cannot handle multiple vacua in general.  They don't mix to any finite order in perturbation theory (remember the degeneracy is symmetry-protected.)

Thank you. A more precise reference to Popov’s book might be helpful.

V. N. Popov, Functional integrals un quantum field theory and statistical physics.
